# inductive proof of two combinatorial identities

Tags: combinatorics

(please be tolerant if this question has already been answered on MSE - i am a newcomer here and it will take some time to adjust to the community ethos)

set

$$
a_{2m}= \sum_{j=0}^m \frac{(-1)^{m-j}2^{2j}}{(m+j)}\binom{m+j}{m-j}
$$
and 
$$
a_{2m+1}= \sum_{j=1}^{m+1} \frac{(-1)^{m+1-j}2^{2j-1}}{(m+j)}\binom{m+j}{m+1-j}
$$
i (think i) have shown by a fairly straightforward generating function approach that:

$$
a_{2m} = \frac1m
$$
and 
$$
a_{2m+1} = \frac2{2m+1}
$$
but if the results are true, one feels there should be an inductive proof. if we write
$$b_{2m} = ma_{2m}
$$
and 
$$b_{2m+1} = \frac{(2m+1)a_{2m+1}}{2}
$$
the result can be expressed as 
$$
b_{2m}=b_{2m+1}=1
$$
and i (think i) have shown that
$$
b_{2m+1} - b_{2m} = b_{2m-1} - 1
$$
but, whilst obviously this is useful progress, it does not (seem to) go quite far enough to give a proof.

can anyone show me how to complete the inductive demonstration?

thank you

Comment: Where by $b$ you mean $a?$

Comment: @IgorRivin i think it is OK as expressed (despite my acknowledged proneness to silly mistakes). the $a$'s are how it comes out from the generating function approach, but the change to the $b$'s just serves to 'normalize' the equations, so that with the $1$'s on the RHS it is more suited to what i'd expect to be a leapfrog method for the inductive proof. i just rechecked the easy cases for $m=2$ i.e $a_4 = \sum_{j=0}^2 = \frac12 - 4 + 4 = \frac12$ and  $a_5 = \sum_{j=1}^3 = 4 - 10 + \frac{32}5 = \frac25$, as asserted

Comment: By the way, Mathematica agrees with your evaluation.

Comment: @IgorRivin modulo silly mistakes i'm confident of the result since it comes from an exercise i set myself to show that $ln \; z^2 = 2ln\; z$ by comparing the series expansions of $ln(1-t)$ and $ln(1-[t(2-t)])$. at first this seemed rather beyond my slender ability to do the algebra , but it became easier as i familiarized myself with the problem. i have never used any math software, but i'd love to try that sometime soon. thank you for your interest btw. i am mainly self-taught, and i sense that you are both an aesthetically conscious mathematician and also a natural teacher. rare combination!

Comment: You are too kind... In an case, you might want to check out Petkovsek/Zeilberger's A=B (free online), they have some very cool stuff of this kind.

Comment: thank you. i have ordered a second-hand copy as the symbolism seems to be mutilated on the adobe file, and to try and read it like that would be more than a labour of love.